# Adding an independent constraint to one bone in an armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I've been trying to use a copy location constraint on individual bones to have them follow face trackers I generated from some footage. Unfortunately every time I apply a constraint to one bone, it applies to all the bones in the armature so they all follow a single tracker (not ideal).

It's weird because I've been scrupulously following a step by step tutorial but this is the one step where its just not working for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated[image]

Comment: You are in the Object Constraint Properties, not in the Bone Constraint Properties. So you applied the constraint to the whole armature. If you add a constraint to a bone it becomes green. (In the right side there are small colored icons below each-other. You have to select the icon two below the current).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much!